# Replace 3d whitespace with comma and whitespace in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

To replace a whitespace with a comma and whitespace in a string I should do something like this:

`$result = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ', ', trim($value));`

The result: `Some, example, here, for, you`

However, I only want to replace the 3d white space, so that the result would look like this:

`Some example here, for you`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like

```
$value = " Some example here for you ";
$result = preg_replace('/^\S+(?:\s+\S+){2}\K\s+/', ',$0', trim($value), 1);
echo $result; // => Some example here, for you
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NFcBSL) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vn4CBS/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `(?:\s+\S+){2}` - two consecutive occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\s+` - (the `$0` in the replacement pattern references this substring) 1+ whitespaces.

Comment: Like this solution more than mine. Much more elegant. Although, it doesn't replace  the whitespace if it's in the end of the string. Not sure what is the expected behavior, though.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte There can't be a whitespace at the end of the string, the `$value` is `trim()`med.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an callback function and control when to replace:

```
<?php

$string = 'Some example here for you';
$i = 0;
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\s+/',function($m) use(&$i){
    $i++;
    if($i == 3) {
        return ', ';
    }
    return ' ';
},$string);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = preg_replace('/^([^\s]+)\s+((?1)\s+(?1))/', '\1 \2,', trim($value));
```

[Test it](https://regex101.com/r/x9NDwb/2)

Explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `([^\s]+)` - capture everything not a space
- `\s+` space 1 or more
- `((?1)\s+(?1))` - `(?1)` repeat first capture group, we do this 2x with a space between, and capture that. I guess you could capture them separately, but what's the point.

The nice thing about `(?{n})` is if you have to change the regex for the word capturing you only have to change it 1 time, not 3.  Probably it doesn't matter here so much, but I like using it...